# jQuery multi-level table sorting

Tags: sorting, tablesorter

I am having following requirement to make sortable data table.  I tried the "jquery.dataTables.min.js", but I can't get along with this plugin.

The requirement is, when I clicking on anyone column the respective column will be getting (Ascending & Descending) sorted out as like as pervasively used jQuery plugins.  if I clicks on another column to be sorted out, the entire table rows should not get sorted out. So it means, whenever clicks on subsequent column header the sorting should happened only between some specific rows.

For the sake of better understanding I put below illusions one by one.

**Default view of table (without sorting)...**

[image]

**After first time sorting (Ascending or Descending - doesn't matter)**

[image]

For instance, Now i am going to click on 4th column (header) of this table...

[image]

Now, sorting is not happening for entire table.  If you look at the red marked area of above illusion, only order is adjusted between two colored rows.

Any ideas?  Can we have any plugins to match this requirement?  Or any jQuery brainstorms to make this workout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both DataTables and Tablesorter allow sorting multiple columns by holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while clicking on the table header(s).

I know what you mean by not getting along with the DataTables plugin, it has a fairly steep learning curve.

I maintain a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), if you are willing to check it out.

---

Ok, I understand now, you don't want to use the shift key. Try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4082/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        sortMultiSortKey: 'which' // default: "shiftKey",
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes I checked this one.  This one is different stuff which I am looking for.  Anyway thanks for your quick response.

Comment: What are you looking for?

Comment: The question seems clear to me. Try out [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4081/) and follow the instructions within the css frame. If that *still* isn't what you are looking for, then yes, it isn't clear so please provide another example.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you are saying.  This is somehow what I am looking for.  Thanks.  But I want to enable the function in mouse click where we have shift+click on table header click.  Is that possible?  As I mentioned, on first click only all column should get respond.  After second or subsequent clicks, the shift+click should get enabled in single mouse click.  Is there any options available in this plugin.  Thanks.

Comment: Great dude.  Really you are taken.  This is what I am looking for.  One more question.  When I clicking first time (any column header) all rows getting sorted out.  Good.  On second click, specific rows only getting sorted out.  I could see that.  That is also very great.  But when I tried third column nothing is happening. Can I continue the same click event for further clicks as like as second click does?

Comment: Yes, clicking on other columns will continue the chain of multiple column sorting. Please note though, that if you click on the first column again it remains as the primary sort column. You can use `ctrl` + click to cancel the sort on a column.